# How do I know when an iOS App Open Ad is dismissed in Xamarin/MAUI?

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin, admob, maui

I am using [`Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds` package](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents) to show Google [App Open Ad](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-open) in my MAUI app. The code below has error handling code removed for brevity.

```cs
this.ad = await AppOpenAd.LoadAsync(
    o.IosUnitId,
    null,
    o.Orientation switch
    {
        AppOpenAdOrientation.Landscape => UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft,
        _ => UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait,
    }
);

var oldHandler = ad.PaidEventHandler;
var openTcs = new TaskCompletionSource();

// The handler below is actually called when the ad show up
ad.PaidEventHandler = v =>
{
    oldHandler?.Invoke(v);
    openTcs.TrySetResult();
};

var root = Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController();
this.ad.PresentFromRootViewController(root);
```

In the [Google's doc on Handle presentation callbacks](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-open#handle_presentation_callbacks), a `GADFullScreenContentDelegate` is needed but I have no idea how I can put it in C# and there is no event/delegate corresponding to this `self.appOpenAd.fullScreenContentDelegate = self;`.

Please advice on the event of ad dismissal. I could do it for Android like this but I can't see the equivalent in Xamarin.iOS:

```cs
this.currAd.FullScreenContentCallback = callback;
```

Comment: According to the method in the document, it can be found that the class corresponding to `GADFullScreenContentDelegate` in the C# code is `FullScreenContentDelegate`. There is a method of `DidDismissFullScreenContent` that monitors the closing of advertisements. You can try to rewrite this method.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT I think so too. I saw `DidDismissFullScreenContent` method but it is a method and not event so I have no idea how I can rewrite it like you suggested. I also cannot inherit `AppOpenAd` because the instance I received is from `AppOpenAd.LoadAsync()`.